# Is there a simple method for left open just like right open for range in switch?

Tags: ios, swift

There is simple if right open [0,1) as the following,

```
let val:  Float = 0
switch val {
case 0..<1:
...
}
```

But for (0, 1], is there a piece of similar simple code?

Comment: You can "cheat" with `switch 1-val` ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard operator to create a left-open range, and there is no standard type to represent a left-open range.

You could define an operator that creates a closed range after adding 1 to the left bound, but you cannot spell it `<..`. From [*The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418):

> If an operator doesn’t begin with a dot, it can’t contain a dot elsewhere. For example, `+.+` is treated as the + operator followed by the `.+` operator.

Comment: Do you mean use a case where is a good option if I do not make an operator?

Comment: I do not understand that sentence.

Comment: switch val { case let x where x < 1 && 0 < x:   ...} or switch val { case let x where x < 1: ... case x < 0: ... }

Comment: You would say `case let x where 0 < x && x <= 1: ...` for a left-open range.